# Android library Card.io showing cannot locate symbol __aeabi_memcpy

Tags: android, cardio

when i am using ndk ABI_fIlter  i am getting error

**"Failed to load native library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol"__aeabi_memcpy" referenced by "/data/app/com.cts.banking-2/lib/arm/libcardioDecider.so"**

ndk
        {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86" ,"x86", "arm64"
        }

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-14',
                    '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
        }}
```

But when i am removing abi filters app is working fine there is no error.
my libraries are loading.

Answer (score 0):

looking at this page helps me:
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md

I then recompile with ndk-build my "custom".so after updating the APP_PLATFORM to my needed android-21 in the Application.mk 
I then copy again the resulted.so file in apps/src/main/jniLibs//

then rebuild my apps in android studio.

it  finally works,good luck